# Sorting a dictionary object

Tags: c#

I've a dictionary object:

```
Dictionary<string, string[]> dictCompanies = new Dictionary<string, string[]>();
```

How do sort this object on its key?

I tried using OrderBy like below, but it does no seem to work

```
dictCompanies .OrderByDescending(c=> c.Key);
```

I'm binding this dictionary object to a checkboxlist in aspx page.

I tried sorting this ListItemCollection using delegate...but still no luck...

Am i missing something here?

Thanks

Comment: Why aren't you using a SortedList?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can't sort an actual [`Dictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xfhwa508.aspx) - the order items come out of it is basically determined by the internal implementation. You might want to look at [`SortedDictionary<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) and [`SortedList<TKey,TValue>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx) though - they still have key/value lookups, but allow you to sort based on the key. You can specify your own `IComparer<T>` if you want to order by the keys in a particular way.

Another option (depending on your situation) would be to stick with the dictionary right up until you need it - then copy it into a list and sort that before binding to the control. Obviously at that point you'd need to refresh the binding every time anything changed, but that may well not be a problem for you.

If your OrderBy statement was really on its own like that, by the way, you need to understand that LINQ operators always operators always take a sequence and return a different sequence (or an aggregate result) - they never modify the sequence in-place. Indeed, they can't as `IEnumerable<T>` is a read-only interface.

Answer (score 1):

Take a look to [SortedDictionary](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/f7fta44c.aspx) and [SortedList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms132319.aspx).

Both have O(log n) retrieval, the main difference is in memory use and speed of insertion and removal:

- SortedList uses less memory than SortedDictionary.
- SortedDictionary has faster insertion and removal operations for unsorted data: O(log n) as opposed to O(n) for SortedList.